# low fps by using cv2.VideoCapture

Tags: python, opencv, camera, frame-rate

I have low FPB ~5, I have checked this code on different cameras logitech c270 and logitech 9000, same situation.

I completed all the tips about turn off right light etc.

```
import urllib.request as urllib
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

while True:

    # Use urllib to get the image and convert into a cv2 usable format
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    hiegh = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

    ret, frame = cap.read()


    # put the image on screen
    cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

cap.release()        
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What should I do for increasing FPS  ?

Comment: Have you tested this on another machine?

Comment: Why have you got references to `urllib` in there? Are you somehow reading across the 'net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Use urllib to get the image and convert into a cv2 usable format
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
hiegh = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
```

Put these lines above while function.

Answer (score 5):

You need to move this line up, **outside** your acquisition loop:

```
 cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

It does a *one-time* only initialisation.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late but, if anyone else is facing this...

Check if you're using the right codec. In my case for a Logitech OrbiCam I had to set it to MJPG:

For C++:

```cpp
cv::VideoCapture camera;
camera.open(0);
auto codec = cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M','J','P','G');
camera.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FOURCC, codec);
```

In Python:

```py
import cv2
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc('m','j','p','g'))
```

For Kotlin:

```kotlin
var capture: VideoCapture = VideoCapture()
camera.open(deviceId)
val mjpg = VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')
capture.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, mjpg.toDouble())
```

etc...

...and then set your target resolution

Answer (score 1):

Try to lower your resolution. You could try 640x480.

example:

```
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 480)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Luis Gonzalez's solution worked for me in Python, but I needed to use uppercase characters like the other examples show:

```
camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'))
```